# In an Elasticsearch instance with 2 indexes and 2 aliases (1 in each index) with the same name how to select data only from one index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elaticsearch v1.4.2 along with NEST .NET client v1.3.1. On the same server and Elasticsearch instance I have 2 indexes (assume IndexEnvironmentA, IndexEnvironmentB). Each of these two indexes holds documents of the same type (TypeA) but they refer to different environments (e.g UAT/DEV). I want to create aliases on these indexes with Routing and Filtering based on a field of Type A (let’s say GroupId).

In my code I have the following snipet that creates the alias in each index.

```
public void CreateAlias(string aliasName) {
            _client.Alias(a => a.Add(
                ad => ad.Index(_indexName)
                    .Alias(aliasName)
                    .Filter<TypeA>(f => f.Term(t => t.GroupId, aliasName))
                    .Routing(aliasName)));
        }
```

After creating the alias I index some data in both indexes using the following code.

```
public void IndexDocument(TypeA t) {
            _client.Index(t, ind => ind
                .Index(_indexName)
                .Routing(t.GroupId)
                .Type(typeof (TypeA))
                .Id(t.Id));
        }
```

When testing the data indexed using Sense and a match_all query I notice the following: When I perform the query against the http://ElasticServerIP/IndexEnvironmentA/TypeA results are returned as I would expect. The same happens with http://ElasticServerIP/IndexEnvironmentB/TypeA.

**Issue:**
When I perform the same query against http://ElasticServerIP/GroupIdX (where GroupIdX is a different alias in each index but with the same name) then I get results from both the indexes. Of course the same happens when I translate the query to C# using the NEST library.

```
_client.Search<TypeA>(s => s.Index(GroupIdX)
                .Types(typeof (TypeA))
                .From(From)
                .Size(Size)
                .Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
```

I can understand why this happens. Elasticsearch cannot know which of the two indexes (actually aliases) I am referring to. If this is the expected behavior does this mean that the aliases are actually of no use in this case and I lose their (or some of their) benefits? Do I have to include the routing value and filter values in all the requests that I send to this Elasticsearch instance?

I’d appreciate any thoughts on this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance the elasticsearch endpoint `PUT /{index}/_alias/{name}` does make it seem like an alias "belongs" to an index, but this is not the case. Aliases don't belong to an index.

When you create an alias for an index you are creating the alias, then adding an index to that alias.

When you create an alias for your other index, you are using the same alias and adding another index to it.

Your alias now refers to two indexes and you'll get results from both. It sounds like you need two aliases if you want to use two filters from separate indexes.

Comment: Do you know if there is an endpoint like `GET /{alias}/{index}/_search`? (I am quite sure that there isn't...)

Comment: This is not what aliases are designed for - they're meant to be used instead of an index name, not in addition to. If you have UAT/DEV data the standard approach is to use separate instances of elasticsearch for each environment, rather than different indexes. Much like the way you'd never have UAT/DEV data mixed together in a SQL database and just refer to each using different table names.